# Tips for coping with a surprisingly high rate of "botnet" sshd login failures?

Tags: linux, ssh, ddos

I just set up 2 new Debian 12 VPS's at once.

One of them worked fine; the other, I appeared to have intermittent connectivity to. I even got as far as writing half of a support ticket, thinking it must be a connectivity issue in their datacenter, but then dug deeper and found out about sshd's "MaxStartups" feature: once there's more than a certain number of connections that have been opened but not yet authenticated, sshd will intentionally start dropping further connections, which is consistent with what I was seeing.

On the VPS that works fine, logs show a malicious attempt roughly once every two minutes, which is what I've come to expect. On the troublesome one, it seems to be around one *every second* on average, so with a default LoginGraceTime of 2 minutes, it makes perfect sense why I was struggling to get in. I've already reduced this to 5 seconds, which just about manages to keep the number of open connections under control. (Both VPS's are already configured to only accept public key auth, so there's no way a malicious attempt can succeed anyway.)

I'm surprised by how quickly the attempts are coming on the troublesome one. They appear to be coming from all different source IPs, so clearly a botnet, and not something I can easily block. fail2ban for example wouldn't do anything here afaik, as it works fully on the source IP.

I'm planning to put a public HTTP server on this VPS, so I'm also concerned that if it's already the target of a botnet attack over SSH, my HTTP server might end up DDOS'd into oblivion before I've even started, and/or attract attention from someone or something scanning for vulnerabilities to exploit. (The other VPS, that's only seeing one attempt every two minutes, I'm planning to put a mail server on - I'm not sure which protocol I should be more concerned about!)

- What rate of malicious attempts should I *expect* to be directed at a randomly chosen IPv4 address?
- Should I take any action in response to this, or just put up with it?

  - Ask my VPS provider if they can change the server's IP since perhaps I just got unlucky and this one was the target of a DDOS against some random other person who since deallocated their IP and it ended up assigned to me?
  - Block SSH from everywhere except another VPS of mine that I can access it through - despite that I'll be ultimately running a public HTTP server on it anyway? (seems a bit pointless to firewall SSH down when HTTP needs to be open - and it would be a moderate inconvenience to me to do this)
  - Just silence log messages for failed attempts? (assuming there are options to do this - I haven't checked yet)
  - Are there alternative SSH server software packages I can use that are more optimised for handling a high rate of malicious attempts? For example, sshd creates a new process for each new connection before auth, which seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead: it should ideally consume as few resources as possible until auth has succeeded.
  - ...any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What rate of malicious attempts should I expect to be directed at a randomly chosen IPv4 address?

The background noise of the internet:  routine, automated, dragnet (rather than targeted specifically at your IPv4 address) scans of large parts of the internet scanning for exposed hosts and services.  A continuous stream of probes, easily resulting in 100's of log-in/abuse attempts per day on an exposed sshd alone (although numbers may range from dozens to (many) thousands with certain provider IP-address ranges being targeted more than others) with sources varying from:

- diligent providers (that may be running vulnerability scanners because they want to warn/disconnect customers when they operate insecure/vulnerable/compromised systems)
- research projects (like for example [shodan.io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shodan_(website)) and others) and other curious  people
- malicious actors (that may be using botnets to execute their probes)
- etc. etc.

> Should I take any action in response to this, or just put up with it?

In general: when you expose a server and service to the internet you should expect connections and most importantly abuse (attempts) from the whole internet.

**If a service is not intended as a public service** then **it shouldn't be exposed  to the whole internet.**
When you can: best practice is to apply access controls. That can take several for forms but common is to limit access to known IP-addresses and/or known IP-address ranges. Or alternatively when you don't exactly know good IP-address ranges, block ranges that are unlikely to ever have a valid access requirement.
Although tying IP-address (ranges) to geographic locations is far from 100% reliable nor fully complete, access lists using Geo-IP data can be very useful in that regard.

Access controls can be set outside of the host, with for example security groups or a firewall appliance. Then the server itself doesn't need to provide any resources to maintain them.

Often more flexible, but also requiring resources from the host itself, are host-based access controls, like a host-based firewall (on Linux netfilter/iptables/nftables) or access controls in the application itself. That can for example often be the only way to set different IP-address restrictions for different users.

When a service is intended **for a public service**, like for example a web server with your public website, **typically you don't apply access controls**, because genuine site visitors are welcome from everywhere.
Often such public services you take the approach: allow access from everywhere, but **detect malicious behaviour and (temporarily) block the IP-address used by the bad actor(s)**. A tool like [Fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) is one such approach, [IDS and IPS systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) another.

<sub>**Example:** An access control list  on the take-away order page and online reservations systems for a local restaurant in let's say Amsterdam, my home town. You wouldn't set that to only allow access for IP-addresses from Amsterdam. That would probably be overly restrictive and for example turn away valid local vistors that were using their mobile phones to access the site.

But on the other hand  blocking IP-address ranges known to be in assigned and in-use outside of Europa and used in for example the regions of Africa, Asia Pacific, North and South America should reduce the number of abuse attempts greatly and is unlikely to impact the number of reservations / take-away orders.

In contrast the access control list for SSH access on that same webserver can  easily be be limited to the static IP-addresses of the site administrators, the gateway of their office and/or when they don't have a static IP-address or a VPN server, to the ranges used by their ISP's.</sub>

> Are there alternative SSH server software packages I can use that are more optimised for handling a high rate of malicious attempts? For example, sshd creates a new process for each new connection before auth, which seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead:

I think and hope that you are greatly over-estimating the actual resource requirements and impact of those login attempts. In the scheme of things the load that a "normal" level of ssh abuse attempts generate on the exposed VPS systems I've seen is negligible compared to real application loads.

> seems a bit pointless to firewall SSH down when HTTP needs to be open

A general approach to security is the [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) ; which in  firewall rules translates to:

- block everything by default
- only allow access to what is needed to those who need it

So it isn't pointless to allow ssh access only from some IP-addresses and rather than the whole world and to do allow the whole world access to ports 80 (to redirect plain to https) and 443 the default https port.

Comment: Great answer. I've accepted this as I think it's the most useful for people in a similar situation that might be missing some of this, although in my particular case, everything here I'm either already doing or doesn't apply. e.g. I do in general want to be able to SSH in from anywhere, on the standard port, for convenience; and I'm still effectively applying "principle of least privilege" by disallowing root login and disallowing any auth methods other than public key.

Comment: I _could_ also block some countries or other IP ranges, but keeping such a blocklist current is a maintenance burden that I really don't want to take on.

Answer (score 3):

I've not previously seen slowloris type attacks on ssh. Looking at the documentation, MaxStartups doesn't seem to care about whether these are from the same client (i.e. you could be facilitating the DOS using this). My first response (depending on the pattern of the attacks) would be to use iptables connlimit (limit connections per client IP).

Fail2ban is the obvious solution for most ssh attacks (I've also used it for HTTP[S] traffic) but do make sure it's configured to use ipset.

Changing IP address is unlikely to help in the long term.

> Block SSH from everywhere except another VPS of mine that I can access it through

Yes - using a jump box is quite common practice. Again, this is something you can do yourself. Just set a default firewall rule for port 22 then whitelist your jumpbox(es). Ssh even has built-in functionality which makes the use transparent, e.g.

```
ssh -J jumpuser@jumpbox.example.com user@targethost.example.com
```

or you can set this in your ssh_config and just `ssh targethost.example.com`:

```
Host jumpbox.example.com
   User: jumpuser
   IdentityFile: ~/.ssh/jumpuser.id_rsa

Host targethost.example.com
   User: user
   ProxyCommand: ssh -q -W %h:%p jumpuser@jumpbox.example.com:22 
   IdentityFile: ~/.ssh/user.id_rsa
```

> Just silence log messages for failed attempts?

I would not advocate this. Feel free to ignore them if you've taken reasonable measures to prevent unauthorized access.

As pepoluan suggests, you can also use a non-standard port and port-knoocking (btw the latter can be [implemented purely in iptables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Port_knocking) without having to use knockd)

Comment: True, can implement purely in iptables. The mechanism is not too intuitive if one is not familiar with how iptables works, though. `knockd` is much simpler to configure :D

Comment: fail2ban doesn't really work here, because the vast majority of the attempted connections were from unique IPs (I did some grepping on the logs to find out how many attempts came from each unique IP). The `-J` option is definitely worth me keeping in mind though - I wasn't aware of it before, but I can certainly think of some situations where it'll come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Change the SSH port from 22 to something else.
2. If the bots still can find your port, install `knockd` and configure your server to implement port-knocking.

Comment: This is a good idea if your threat model is a lot more paranoid than mine. It's not something I'm going to do in my particular situation though as I wish to keep the ability to SSH in from anywhere on the default port without additional steps, and I believe requiring pubkey auth to be sufficient to keep out bad actors in my case.

Comment: Well, in my experience deploying secure Infrastructure, 90-95% of the time attempts at port 22 is driven by automated pentesting tools, ran by either skiddies or freelance grey/white hats. Skiddies that do spray-and-pray messes up my logs, so I move the port to something other than 22 & 23. Just doing that reduces a LOT of the cruft in the logs, enabling me to see more serious attemps.

Comment: Another benefit: Repeated attempts at port 22 / 23 == actor trying to be bad. Definitely not one of the good guys (who all knows the SSH has moved to a new place). Into the blocklist bin they go! :D

Comment: PS: Although SSH has moved, I still do some logging with `rate` on ports 22 & 23. A cron job can filter out these attempts and add the offending source IP into an ipset containing addresses to tarpit and/or honeypot. Who says sysadmins can't have fun with wanna-be-crackers 

Answer (score 1):

So, after about five days of this particular VPS being offline (it's a hobby project that I'm working on sporadically anyway), I booted it back up to see if the attackers had given up trying to DDOS an IP that wasn't responding to anything. But no, the moment it was back online the connection attempts were right back at the high rate I saw last time.

In the end, I deleted and recreated the VPS instance: this gave it a different IP (so I didn't have to bother *asking* for one!) and indeed the connection attempts dropped to the rate I am used to seeing on VPS's - at least a hundred times less than the original high rate.

I think for what I am trying to do, my existing security measures were already sufficient, so I had simply gotten unlucky with the IP allocation choice in terms of the volume of attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose SSH via public ip, it will get scanned sooner or later, and threat actors will try authentication attempts, no matter the VPS provider or network.

I would harden you ssh configuration using an ansible playbook like this:
https://github.com/dev-sec/ansible-collection-hardening/tree/master/roles/ssh_hardening

Or this playbook, that hardens the whole server:
https://github.com/konstruktoid/ansible-role-hardening

---

And I would also recommend fail2ban.
Fail2Ban: ban hosts that cause multiple authentication errors
Fail2Ban scans log files like /var/log/auth.log and bans IP addresses conducting too many failed login attempts. It does this by updating system firewall rules to reject new connections from those IP addresses, for a configurable amount of time

---

Or you can maybe create a VPN connection to the network of your VPS/ creating a VPN server in your VPS using OpenVPN (for example) , and putting SSH behind the VPN, and not exposing it to the internet.